# How to get values from multiple form submission in Java

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a form which has two tabs.On load it will fetch me values to that tab's input fields if available else the user must enter the details and save it.And on save I send it to a servlet and get processed.Below is the code for jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/responsive-tabs.css " /> 
<header class="panel-heading vtab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#reference-0">
                Reference 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#reference-1">
                Reference 2
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</header>

<div class="panel-body vcontent">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <%     

            String refname[] = new String[2];
            String refmob[] = new String[2];
            String refdesg[] = new String[2];
            String refmail[] = new String[2];
           //get ref data here
                      for (int i = 0; i < refData.length; i++) {
                refname[i] = //get detail
                refmob[i] = //get detail
                refdesg[i] = //get detail
                refmail[i] = //get detail


        %>
        <div id="reference-0" class="tab-pane">
            <form action="profileref" name="form<%=i%>" method="post"  class="clearfix">
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refname[i]%>" name="refname<%=i%>" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference Name" id="refname0"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refdesg[i]%>" name="refdesg<%=i%>" class="form-control" placeholder="Designation" id="refdesg0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refmail[i]%>" name="refmail<%=i%>" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="refmail0" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refmob[i]%>" name="refmob0<%=i%>" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" id="refmob0" />
                </div>

            </div>
<div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info m-r-10" id="save">Save</button>

    </div>
</form>
        </div>


<!--        <div id="reference-1" class="tab-pane">
            <form action="profileref" name="form1"  method="post"  class="clearfix">
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refname[1]%>" name="refname1" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference Name" id="refname1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refdesg[1]%>" name="refdesg1" class="form-control" placeholder="Designation" id="refdesg1" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refmail[1]%>" name="refmail1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="refmail1" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" value="<%=refmob[1]%>" name="refmob1" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" id="refmob1" />
                </div>

            </div>
<div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info m-r-10" id="save">Save</button>

    </div>  
 </form>
        </div>       -->


        <script>
            $("#reference-0:first-child").addClass("active");


        </script>
        <!--
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info m-r-10">Save</button>

                                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info select-tab" value="1">Next</button> 
                                            </div>  </form>-->

        <%

            }  

        %>
</div>


</div>
</form>
```

I tried using loop to get the data but i was only able to get tab 1 details ,tab 2 details are null. I also tried using 2 forms this also not working according to my wish.What am I doing wrong here.Below I have attached my servlet code(Only given the code inside the servlet)

```
 String refname[] = new String[2];
            String refdesg[] = new String[2];
            String refmail[] = new String[2];
            String refmob[] = new String[2];
            refname[0] = request.getParameter("refname0");
            refdesg[0] = request.getParameter("refdesg0");
            refmail[0] = request.getParameter("refmail0");
            refmob[0] = request.getParameter("refmob0");

            out.print(refname[0]);
            out.print(refmail[0]);
            out.print(refdesg[0]);

            refname[1] = request.getParameter("refname1");
            refdesg[1] = request.getParameter("refdesg1");
            refmail[1] = request.getParameter("refmail1");
            refmob[1] = request.getParameter("refmob1");

            out.print(refname[1]);
            out.print(refmail[1]);
            out.print(refdesg[1]);
```

Comment: did you try debugging ? It should not happen actually. You must receive all the data

Comment: NO i get only the values from 1st tab second tab prints nullnullnull